# Why is this TypeScript exhaustive switch check not working?

Tags: typescript

Why does the following switch default case not lead to an exhaustive check where item is correctly identified as never?

```
enum Type {
    First,
    Second
}

interface ObjectWithType {
    type: Type;
}

const array: ObjectWithType[] = [];

for (const item of array) {
    switch (item.type) {
        case Type.First:
            break;
        case Type.Second:
            break;
        default: {
            const unhandledItem: never = item;
            throw new Error(`Unhandled type for item: ${unhandledItem}`);
        }
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gKCpqAxAlgJwGcAXAGgywGVgBjAexABM0BfNNXEY4fAMwEMayAPIAjAFa1iAdVzEAFvCSoKmYomAAuWBoDcrdvRAko-fPn5xtYyTRlzFGgNoBdKAF4or-Wl518UAAURiZywNB0vKbmlgCUKlhQhADucjTyQWEQAHTqSPHoiYk0-ITISsDZeETEmqpFiaL4wPwA1voNmCVlOkjZ1EaMdZ1FTS3t9YmMwAJgADa1CSNYIcRQYCDy-ExzwIwAktwQ2iDAAG48HlBZHctq8vh0yVCnzwCi5v6BAAYAqpvbRi7RhQPLIPwBLLaAAkKA2Wx2e0O4RY31itwabESbBYQA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @thedude said, the problem is that you're using `item` instead of `item.type`.

You can correct the problem and make the code simpler by grabbing `type` from `item` early and then using that; in the `default`, the type of `type` will automatically be narrowed to `never`:

```typescript
for (const item of array) {
    const {type} = item;
    switch (type) {
        case Type.First:
            break;
        case Type.Second:
            break;
        default: {
            throw new Error(`Unhandled type for item: ${type}`);
            // The type here is automatically narrowed  ^^^^  to `never`
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gKCpqAxAlgJwGcAXAGgywGVgBjAexABM0BfNNXEY4fAMwEMayAPIAjAFa1iAdVzEAFvCSoKmYomAAuWBoDcrdvRAko-fPn5xtYyTRlzFGgNoBdKAF4or-Wl518UAAURiZywNB0vKbmlgCUKlhQIcSo6kgsHlBhEPqJhADucjTyQWnA8eiJiTT8hMhKwAB0eETEmqpViaL4wPwA1rmdSbX1Go3URoztQ1XdvQMdiYzAAmAANm0JM1gK+HT5UCDABwCi5v6BAAYAqiDy-ExrwIxQZVB+AdnaACQoZSyXWKDTpsRJsFhAA)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because it's not the `item` that has `never` type, it's the `item.type`.

If you modify your code like so, it will work:

```
const unhandledItem: never = item.type;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
```